# C++ Calculator Skipping Else Statement

Tags: c++

I was making a simple calculator in C++. However the program does not completely function the way it should. When run, the trig if statement executes fine, however, the basic arithmetic else statement doesn't work. I have determined that the code is not executing the else statement and was wondering how to fix it. The code inside the else statement works fine, as I have commented out the if statement. Help?

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>


int main()
{
    double input = 0;
    double firstnumber = 0;
    double secondnumber = 0;


    std::string function;
    std::string operation;


    std::cout << "Enter your calculation: ";
    std::cin >> function;   


    if(function == "sin" || "cos" || "tan")
    {
        if(function == "sin")
        {
            std::cin >> input;
            std::cout << "The sine is " << sin(input) << std::endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
        else if(function == "cos")
        {
            std::cin >> input;
            std::cout << "The cosine is " << cos(input) << std::endl;
            system("PAUSE");

        }
        else if(function == "tan")
        {
            std::cin >> input;
            std::cout << "The tangent is " << tan(input) << std::endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
    }
    else
    {       

        firstnumber = ::atof(function.c_str());
        std::cin >> operation;
        std::cin >> secondnumber;


        double valueadd = firstnumber + secondnumber;
        double valuesubtract = firstnumber - secondnumber;
        double valuemultiply = firstnumber * secondnumber;
        double valuedivide = firstnumber / secondnumber;


        if(operation == "+")
        {      
            std::cout << " = " << valueadd << std::endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
        else if(operation == "-")
        {          
            std::cout << " = " << valuesubtract << std::endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
        else if(function == "*")
        {
            std::cout << " = " << valuemultiply << std::endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
        else if(function == "/")
        {
            std::cout << " = " << valuedivide << std::endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }

        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `(function == "sin" || "cos" || "tan")` is always true.

Comment: But why even have this check anyway? You (are trying to) check if it's `"sin"`, `"cos`" or `"tan"`, and if it is you immediately turn around and do it again, this time individually. Just have a big if-chain, trig and all.

Comment: @GManNickG yeah, the check is actually completely meaningless since he checks it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong.

```
if(function == "sin" || "cos" || "tan")
```

It should be

```
if((function == "sin") || (function == "cos") || (function == "tan"))
```

Note that the check is actually meaningless because you already check for them each individually. You could tidy this up by doing this in a `if`, `else if`, `else` chain.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if(function == "sin" || "cos" || "tan")
```

into:

```
if ((function == "sin") || (function == "cos") || (function == "tan"))
```

What you have first calculates the expression `"sin" || "cos" || "tan"` and then tries to compare the string with that.

But, in fact, it's not really necessary to have this two-step process. You can simply do something like this:

```
if (function == "sin") {
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "The sine is " << sin (input) << std::endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
} else if (function == "cos") {
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "The cosine is " << cos (input) << std::endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
} else if (function == "tan") {
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "The tangent is " << tan (input) << std::endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
} else {
    // It's neither sin, cos nor tan if you get here.

    firstnumber = ::atof (function.c_str ());

    // and the rest of your stuff in here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write out each condition separately. The following line of code compiles but it doesn't do what you think:

```
if (function == "sin" || "cos" || "tan")
```

Change it to the following:

```
if (function == "sin" || function == "cos" || function == "tan")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do something different for each trig function, you should just have a single `if...else if...else if...else if...else` chain. There is no need to nest the if statements as you have. In fact, it is probably less efficient because you check each condition twice.